# 2 direction listview swipe using SwipeListView

Tags: android-listview

I'm using SwipeListView from [THIS](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/) tutorial.

In this tutorial they open 1 type of custom row by swipe right, and dismiss the row by swipe left.

I want to use it a little bit different.

I want to open 1 type of row by swiping left and other type by swiping right.

I tried first to use the bellow code to do it, the code use one custom row and If the user swipe right I'm hiding the left side and vise verse(This is from the main actvity):

```
public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
        Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
        View v = swipelistview.getChildAt(position);
        if (v == null) return;
        if (right) {
            v.findViewById(R.id.example_itemparameters).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          } else {        
            v.findViewById(R.id.example_itemparameters).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }

    }
```

The problem of this code is that the "getview" of the adapter called only for the item that are shown, so if I scroll the list down to the items that are not shown first, the "swipelistview.getChildAt(position);" is null().

I tried to follow how to load all the items to the list view and nothing work for me.

Hope that someone met with this problem and can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue!!!!

Thanks to this man - [Question](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/111)

This is how my method "onStartOpen" look like :

```
@Override
public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
    View v = swipelistview.getChildAt(position - swipelistview.getFirstVisiblePosition()); 

    if (v == null) return;
    if (right) {
        v.findViewById(R.id.example_itemparameters).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      } else {        
        v.findViewById(R.id.example_itemparameters).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

}
```

The problem was that the "GetView" method of the adapter, load just the shown items, so my problem was to find the "real" position after the "swipelistview" updated (usually by scrolling up and down the listview).

then the real position is - **position - swipelistview.getFirstVisiblePosition()**

And in the end you can do what do you want with the internal objects.

In my case, if I swipe left I'm display 2 Buttons and if I swipe right I display textview.

Hope that this answer will help for other, because it takes me too long to find this **EASY** solution.